# Grails: Error using liferay plugin

Tags: java, grails, plugins, liferay

I'm having this problem with the grails liferay-plugin:

```
localhost_liferay_portlet_WEB_INF_grails_app_views_test_view_gsp: 17: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 17, column 170.
1 error
```

Here's the gsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
<div>
<h1>View Page</h1>
The map returned by renderView is passed in. Value of mykey: ${mykey}
<form action="${portletResponse.createActionURL()">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Can someone give me any clues?
Thanks,
Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its just an escaping problem in your post, but you are missing a right "}" in you form action after createActionURL().